# Only backup files of a certain type using Windows Server Backup

Tags: windows, backup

How do I use Windows Server Backup to only backup files of a certain type?

For example: `*.doc`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the GUI, what you can only do is specifying file types to *exclude*, but not the other way around. [wbadmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wbadmin) and [Windows Server Backup cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706683.aspx), its command line and Powershell counterparts, however, allow you to do that.

For wbadmin, see `-include` parameters of [wbadmin start backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083(WS.10).aspx). For Power Shell, take a look at [New-WBFileSpec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706672.aspx) cmdlet. Both of them allows you to specify inclusion pattern using wildcards. wbadmin will probably get your job done faster though. [This article](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2010/04/01/backup-basics-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) provides samples of using both approach.

Note that these tools are just alternative interfaces to Windows Server Backup. You can start backup from wbadmin and still monitor progress from GUI.